# JavaScript - Objects Id

Tags: javascript

From what I learnt in JS it's possible to use `document.getElementById` to get access to manipulate tag.

But since I started using objects, I don't see how is it possible to connect object with for example `<div>`'s id.

So to be clear if I have `<div id="box"></div>` and then in JS document:
`var x = document.getElementById("box");` I can use `x` to manipulate that div.
That is all clear, but when I try something like this:

`var x ={};` and then put methods inside object, how to set this `x` to be able to manipulate `<div>`?

I hope I was clear. :)

Comment: You already have a variable `x` containing a reference to your object, and you can just call methods on that: `x.method()`. There is no need for `getElementById` or stuff, which is **only** for *DOM elements*.

Comment: Do you mean `var X={ box:document.getElementByIs("box") , ....}`. And X.box.something

Comment: Nol, you weren't clear. First off, `var x {};` is a syntax error. Second, describe *what* you want to do, not how you are trying to do it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: indeed i made syntax error, I meant var x = {}; I wanted to make one object with methods instead of have var and functions.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is object. Well, almost.. getElementById() returns object, so you can modify it properties as your wish:

```
var x = document.getElementById("div1");
x.newFunc = function() {
  this.innerHTML = "some string";
};
x.newFunc();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "almost"?

Comment: `null` is not an object, for example. Other primitives aren't, either, until boxed (for example, `3` is not an object until auto-boxing turns it into a `Number` instance).

Comment: `null` is tricky :), typeof(null) results in 'object', but it is not. And definetly other primitives: number, boolean, string, undefined - are not objects.

Comment: My  comment was supposed to provoke you to provide this additional explanation. I guess most people perfectly know what is and what isn't an object, however you used an unfortunate word "everything" without giving such informative context to it.